# exec sp_executesql statement causes error "expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected"

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please could someone help me with how to get the following function to work. I have found a northwind example that works fine but by changing it with the syntax that I need. When all the lines are selected I get an error stating an expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'effec'. The statement I need amended is the following:

```
select max(person_sid) from dim_person
where [Effective_To] <='2015-10-01'
group by person_id_number

declare @sql nvarchar(50), @dt datetime;

set @dt = '2015-10-01';

set @sql = N'SELECT max(person_sid) FROM dim_person WHERE effective_to <= @date';

exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@date datetime',@dt;
```

Comment: Well, of course if you just select the last line it'll say `@sql must be declared` - it is declared a few lines above. What happens if you just select the initial `select....` three lines? Does that run ok?

Comment: Hi there, yeah that all works fine, I get the outputted column with the data in, it's only that last exec last that doesn't seem to work with everything else.

Comment: Count 50 characters along your dynamic sql string. See the 45-50th char is `effec`

Comment: You havn't group by clause in @sql

Comment: Thank you for your help everyone! I have changed the nvarchar to 400 and it works perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining @sql as nvarchar(50)

However you are filling it with more characters...

Try to enlarge its size,
lets say:

```
DECLARE @Sql AS NVARCHAR(4000)
```

Comment: Ack, I was seconds away from this answer.

Answer (score 1):

use the below script. Give sufficient width for the variable `@sql` for accommodating the query.

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX), @dt datetime;

set @dt = '2015-10-01';

set @sql = N'SELECT max(person_sid) FROM dim_person WHERE effective_to <= @date';

exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@date datetime',@dt;
```